# How to build a grid container taking the full screen size in React Native?

Tags: react-native, responsive-design, android-emulator, css-grid

I'm just starting Mobile Development and I must say I find it quite hard to make a React Native mobile app responsive without the units like **vw** or **vh** widely used in Web Development.

- Do you know some tips to adapt the components width and height according to the screen size ?
- And how do you easily check whether your app is responsive without having to open a new emulator with a different screen size all the time ? (I'd rather not use Expo)

For example, I want to build a grid container taking the full width and height of the device screen and I didn't find any easy way to get it.

I've tried to get the dimensions of the screen with `Dimensions.get("window").height` and `Dimensions.get("window").width`

and then I fixed the size of each card of the grid to a percentage of the screen width and height but I'm not convinced : I have to add dependencies to all the margins and other components in the page to the size of each card so it's still tricky for something I could do easily in pure CSS with flex and its gap property (which doesn't exist in React Native).

Answer (score 0):

In react-native we use `<View>` tag instead of `<grid/>` and if you want to add full screen to that root `<View>` tag then add style as flex:1

like this

<View style ={{
flex: 1,
alignContent: 'center'
}}>